# Clear PowerShell while process is running

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

Every online guide for clearing the PowerShell says to use the command `clear`, but what if I have a process currently running? On Mac OSX, I can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to clear the console at any point. Is there an equivalent command on Windows. For reference, I need this often when I am running a server and I want to trigger a client-side event and see what the server outputs from only that event.

Comment: CTRL + L clears the window but you need to try if it fits your needs (probably not!) because when PowerShell is running a command, it won't respond to anything else that runs in the foreground

Answer (score -1):

There are two commands you can use namely cls or clear

Clear the output by typing and executing either one of the above mentioned commands in PowerShell Examples: cls or clear

https://www.carnaghan.com/knowledge-base/how-to-clear-the-screen-in-windows-powershell/

Comment: I don't think this works while a command is currently running